# Mac Qt4: PyQt 4.8 installation error (Need help)

Tags: qt, macos, pyqt

hope someone of you can help me. I'm new to mac and qt, so please forgive me if I ask some dumb questions. So to the problem. I want to install PyQt 4.8 on the macbook (Mac OS X 10.6.4). 
First I installed Qt 4.7 like in this description http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/install-mac.html. Then I installed sip 4.11.2 (without --arch=i386), here the how-to page (http://www.expobrain.net/2010/06/22/install-pyqt4-in-snow-leopard). After that I tried to install PyQt 4.8 (without --use-arch=i386), but I get an error. I googled it, no success. I don't know what to do. I try to build it from source, because I need to install a lot more packages, like qimage2ndarray. And I heard that with the .dmg (binary) you can have some trouble. May be someone can help me. Hope I don't need to reinstall the whole OS.
Here the error.

```
Olis-MacBook-Pro:PyQt-mac-gpl-4.8 opetra$ python configure.py build
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
Error: Failed to determine the layout of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I solved the problem. I had to set the arch, in my case to x86_64, for all three. Not only for sip and PyQt. Without it, qt was compiling PowerPC arch as default. Don't know why, I have a macbook pro 2010 with an i5. Thought the configuration would automatic recognize that.